# Objective C map view delegate viewForAnnotation for MKAnnotation gets just called after click

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have a simple Map view. It has a method

```
-(void)loadAndDisplayPois{
NSLog(@"loadAndDisplayPois");
 if(mapView.annotations.count > 0)
     [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
self.pois = [self loadPoisFromDatabase];
NSLog(@"self.pois.count: %i", self.pois.count);
[mapView addAnnotations:self.pois];
NSLog(@"mapView.annotations.count: %i",mapView.annotations.count);}
```

This method gets called, and I am sure that the method gets called because of the Log, after I downloaded data and saved it into the database. The class which handles the download executes after saving the data to the database `[self.senderObj performSelector:@selector(loadAndDisplayPois)];` Where senderObj is the MapViewControlller. The count Log from the pois array shows 4 after the first time I clicked. But no Annotations on the view, because `viewForAnnotation` is not called (one Annotation in the array ( my current position)). After I execute the method again by clicking a TEST button shows everything on the map.

The `viewForAnnotation` method gets called after `viewWillAppear` and after I clicked the TEST button.

It is driving me nuts since 2 days. I cant anymore ...

Comment: Ok, got it, sorry. It was a mistake in the delegate in another class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call viewForAnnotation manually, you have to indicate the class where you show the map is delegate of MKMapView

In your `.h`

```
 @interface yourViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate>
```

EDIT:

I used this code on a project and worked for me:

```
- (void)updateAnnotations {
    if (self.mapView != nil && self.mapView.annotations != nil) {
        NSArray *annotationsCopy = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.mapView.annotations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"!(self isKindOfClass: %@)", [MKUserLocation class]]]];

        [self.mapView removeAnnotations:annotationsCopy];
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < [appDelegate.centrosComerciales count] ; i++) {
        CC *ccAct = (CC *)[appDelegate.centrosComerciales objectAtIndex:i];
        CMapPoint *mp = [[CMapPoint alloc] initWithCC:ccAct];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:mp];
        [mp release];
    }
}
```

Instead of removing the mapView.annotations I removed a copy of the annotations, without the user location annotation.

The updateAnnotations method is called on the viewWillAppear.

It's very similar to your code, but I remove annotationsCopy instead removing mapView.annotations directly.

Comment: thx. But I have it. The problem is, that the method is not called the first time, I do have to press a button which executes the same method the update the Annotations

Comment: `(self.mapView != nil && self.mapView.annotations != nil)` is redundant. You can remove `!= nil` for the exact same result, and even the entire first half. If `mapView` is nil, there's no way `mapView.annotations` can exist. // This is more concise and, in practice, is no different: `(self.mapView.annotations)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I narrowed it even more down. But I still dont understand it.

```
if(mapView.annotations.count > 0)
    [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
self.pois = [self loadPoisFromDatabase];
[mapView addAnnotations:self.pois];
```

I execute this code by a button, it works. Same code by called by another class, does't work. WHY????

Where is the difference?